# Count SQL records from different columns

Tags: mysql, sql, count, counting, points

I'm working on a voting/contest system (PHP and SQL) where users need to select their top 5 favorite candidates. Their favorite number one gets 5 points, their favorite number two 4 etc.

Example voting:

C = Candidate

```
C_3 5-points
C_1 4-points
C_5 3-points
C_2 2-points
C_4 1-points
```

All votes will be stored in a MySQL table, like sow:

```
ID 5_POINTS 4_POINTS 3_POINTS 2_POINTS 1_POINTS
1  C_4      C_2      C_1      C_5      C_3
2  C_5      C_3      C_2      C_4      C_1
3  C_4      C_1      C_3      C_5      C_2
4  C_1      C_4      C_2      C_3      C_5
```

The rank based on above votes should be:

```
1. Candidate 4 - 16 Points
2. Candidate 1 - 13 Points
3. Candidate 2 - 11 Points
4. Candidate 3+5 - 10 Points
```

How is it possible to get a query-output like above?
I tried multipe things but nothing works. It would be nice if someone can point me in the right direction...

Comment: Speaking of candidates, this is a candidate for [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) into a relational form that's easier to work with.

Comment: I'd change that schema for a table putting candidates and users in the voted for/gave points relation. I.e. the table had three columns, the user ID, the candidate ID and the number of points. Then your problem can be solved with a simple aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the record in the below format

```
ID CANDIDATE POINTS
1 C_4 5
2 C_2 4
3 C_1 3
4 C_5 2
5 C_3 1
6 C_5 5
7 C_3 4
8 C_2 3
9 C_4 2
10 C_1 1
11 C_4 5
12 C_1 4
13 C_3 3
14 C_5 2
15 C_2 1
16 C_1 5
17 C_4 4
18 C_2 3
19 C_3 2
20 C_5 1
```

This way, you can get the top rankers by sum their points e.g. `SELECT sum(Points) from tablename`